# SoapUI Conditional Goto step using data source param with null value

Tags: soapui, assert, goto

I'm using excel data source in soapUI.
some of the cells in my data source are blank

for example, not all users has packageID:

```
user    age     packageID
a       18  
b       21      123456
c       11
```

I want to add Conditional Goto step, if the packageID is empty go to the target step

I tried:

```
${DataSource# packageID} == null
```

but the it fails, logs:

> Missing matching condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition Goto works based off of the last success test step response, it doesn't consider dataSource step though. So this would not work for you.

Also, the value will most likely not be null but rather an empty string. So instead you will want to check for `""`. But to be safe you could just use a `|` and check for both.

The solution would look like this:

1. DataSource
2. Groovy Script
3. ...(other teststeps like requests)
4. DataSource Loop(DataSource Step = DataSource, Target Step = Groovy Script)

And the groovy script would look like this (added logging for debugging purposes):

```
def packageID = context.expand('${DataSource#packageID}')

if(packageID == "" | packageID == null)
{
    log.info("Empty value found for: " + packageID);
    testRunner.gotoStepByName( "DataSource Loop")
}
else
    log.info("Coninue for: " + packageID);
```

Answer (score 2):

The desired solution is **Conditional Goto** evaluation:

```
'${DataSource#packageID}'='false'
```

or

```
matches('${DataSource#packageID}','false')
```

Notes:

- evaluation is XPath here, = instead of ==,
- context parameters and their values are always strings, so both have to be quoted
- pretty much anything can be put as condition
- nobody likes to put tiny groovy scripts everywhere, so this is a nice visual way

Answer (score 1):

In SOAPUI the conditions in Conditional Goto step must be and XPath expression, in XPath equal operator is `=`. So use one equal symbol `=` instead of `==`. I don't have the SOAPUI PRO therefore I can't add datSource and I can't try it, but I think that you can achieve this with `empty` or `exists` XPath functions, try with:

`exists(${DataSource#packageID}) = false`

or

`empty(${DataSource#packageID})`

EDIT:

If the answer above doesn't work, you can try to make the conditional step with groovy, add a groovy testStep in your testCase and try with this script:

```
if( context.expand('${DataSource#packageID}') == null)
   testRunner.gotoStepByName( "Request 1")
else
   testRunner.gotoStepByName( "Request 2")
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: No. Now i get "Not condition True for current response" and name of another test case